# Is there AI on the server side for Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, server

Do all the Stack Exchange sites have artificial intelligence programs running on the server side?

Comment: No, it is all Real Intelligence....

Comment: The only part that might have some AI is the anti spam system, which is being fed by spam reports and over time learns to identify spam and block it before it's even posted. But we can't know for sure if it's really AI or not, the details of that system are all secret on purpose.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that?

It's "run" by the intelligence (real or otherwise) of its users.

Real people (for the most part) ask questions and real people (for the  most part) answer them. The Stack Exchange servers don't do anything more than deliver lots and lots of webpages very quickly to lots and lots of users.

There are algorithms that run to see if there are any related questions - but they work by searching the database for words and phrases in your question, but - as far as I know - that's about it.

If there's any AI involved it's not at the Stack Exchange side.

Comment: i mean, when we ask question there is such a features.

Comment: @user7549997 - what do you think this theoretical AI does? All that happens when you ask a question is that it gets stored in a database and then rendered when you view the page.

Comment: i mean like bot programs, check grammer, does question meets quality standards. such a pop ups

Comment: @user7549997 - ah. Then perhaps you should edit your question to make it clearer. However, I think the quality standards check is quite straightforward and there is no grammar or spelling checking done for you.

Comment: anyway, why does stack exchangeers always need perfect and expert questions ?

Comment: @user7549997 because all the other sites do the less then perfect questions. We don't want to copy that.